# How to create list of object as foreign keys in Entity Framework and fill the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm trying to create database for my Android application using Entity Framework with a code-first approach (I think).

My database would look like this:

[image]

In the `Restaurant` table, I would like to have a list of `Dish` table elements and same for `Groceries` in the `Dish` table.

I tried to do it like this:
https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/41048304/entity-framework-class-with-list-of-object

But I can't see the FK in migration or in the database.

Next I tried it like this code below (here are my classes) :

```
public class Restaurant
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdRestaurant { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String NameOfRestaurant { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String PictureOfRestaurant { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}  

public class Dish
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdDish { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String NameOfDish { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String PictureOfDish { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Double Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Double CalorieValue { get; set; }
   
    public virtual int? IdRestaurant { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Grocery> Groceries{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}  

public class Grocery
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdGrocery { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String NameOfGrocery { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String PictureOfGrocery { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Double CalorieValue { get; set; }

    public virtual int? IdDish { get; set; }
    public virtual Dish Dish { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

But it didn't work.

After I solve this problem, I would like to add some elements in database. Tried it like this (just to test if it works, but with no success) :

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Restaurants.Models.MojDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Restaurants.Models.MojDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.

        context.Groceries.AddOrUpdate(x => x.IdGrocery,
            new Grocery()
            {
                NameOfGrocery = "Carrot",
                PictureOfGrocery = "anhnahdagd",
                CalorieValue = 55
            },
            new Grocery()
            {
                NameOfGrocery = "Tomato",
                PictureOfGrocery = "wqeqwewqeewqqew",
                CalorieValue = 89
            },
            new Grocery()
            {
                NameOfGrocery = "Potato",
                PictureOfGrocery = "zuuuiitutuitu",
                CalorieValue = 110
            }
        );

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And when I add a migration with:

```
Add-Migration SeedMigration
```

it just creates a blank migration :

```
public partial class SeedMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

So how can I add data into the table?

Comment: Remove this line AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false; and then run add- migration

Comment: @viveknuna even when i make it true or delete it, migrations is still blank, tried to remove and make controllers again (it helped the first time, but now it doesnt work anymore, migration is blank)

Answer (score 0):

**Create foreign key**

To create a foreign key, you have to add a line that is an `[Index]`, with a name (in this example) `U_FK` and then add `[Required]` at the end.

```
[Index]
public int U_FK { get; set; } // Foreign Key - User
[Required]
```

**Create list of foreign key**

To create a foreign key, you have to add a line that is an `[Index]`, with a name (in this example) `U_FK` and then add `[Required]` at the end.

```
[Index]
public List<int> U_FK { get; set; } // Foreign Key - User List
[Required]
```

**Add elements to database**

To add elements you first call the class name and create a new instance of it, in this case exp. Then you assign it's values (as long as they aren't required you don't have to). After that you load your context and save it in `ExampleList` you created (will show example below).

```
Example exp = new Example
{
    Active = true,
    Titel = InputTitel,
    Views = 0,
};

using(var context = new ForumDbContext())
{
    context.Examples.Add(exp);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Create a Context (if you don't already have one)**

In your specific case you can replace Context with your already existing seed migration.

```
public class GlobalRef
{
   public static string dbConnectionString = "Data Source = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = FForumDB; Integrated Security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
}

public class ForumDbContext : DbContext
{
   public ForumDbContext() : base(GlobalRef.dbConnectionString) {}
    
   public DbSet<Example> Examples{ get; set; }
}
```

**Get Value from database**

To get for example the ID of another Datatable. You first get the context again. Then you loop through each element in that Database where it's active and order it by views. You can also add `.First()` to only get the first element that was returned.

```
using(ForumDbContext context = new ForumDbContext())
{
    foreach(Example example in context.Examples.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Examples WHERE Active='1' ORDER BY Views" ).ToList<Example>())
    {
        int exampleid = example.E_ID;
    }
}
```

**Get all Values from database and put them in a List**

```
List<int> exampleFKs = new List<int>;
using(ForumDbContext context = new ForumDbContext())
{
    foreach(Example example in context.Examples.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Examples WHERE Active='1' ORDER BY Views" ).ToList<Example>())
    {
        exampleFKs.Add(example.E_ID);
    }
 }
```

Comment: ty for reply.The issue i have is that i dont know how to make a List of FK in e.g list of Dish in Restaurants(dont know the syntax). I can make one FK of Dish in Restaurnat, but not the list.   Second i dont know where to put insert into database code,(i have created context and its called MojDbContext). Could you please make me an example

Comment: I added how to create a List of Foreign Keys but I'm unsure what you mean "where to put insert into database code"?

Comment: Where do i write your Add to Database code? As you can see i tought i write it in Configuration.cs file but it doesnt work. And i still dont understand how is [Index]
public int U_FK { get; set; } // Foreign Key - User
[Required] a List

Comment: Okay got it I misunderstood something. I'll edit my code.

Comment: And you add the "Add to Database Code" in your MainFunction.

Comment: Thats my Startup.cs class? If so, do i put it in Startup or  in Configuration?

Comment: Yeah put it in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216869/discussion-between-sinor-bodl-and-mathewhd).